# neo4j node property type suggestion, indexes or parent object relationship?

Tags: neo4j

New to neo4j so I wanted to ask a basic question about database schema design.

Assuming 2 object types

- Users
- Posts

Where users can like posts and there will be some very large amont of users and posts, should the object type be stored as a property of the node?  Or, should I just create two indexes one for users, another for posts?  Finally, should I just create a parent object for Users and a different one for Posts and they all have an "isA" relationship.  I saw someone mention that would create a supernode penalty, which I'm not sure what that means.

I know that it always depends on the situation but what would be the right design in the most common case scenarios?

Comment: Personally, I'm in favor of the 'Add the type as a property' scenario, but why not do both? Creating an index won't incur much of a penalty which makes it easy to perform a lookup on certain node types.

Comment: I agree, do both. Lookup is faster with the index, but you can check during traversals / cypher-queries with the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've added the nodeType property and set up a separate auto_index property for each which seems to work well.

I'm curious to see how this will change when node types gets introduced in Neo4j 2.0